# PHP dio_read taking taking 1 minute to execute each task

Tags: php, serial-port

We are trying to read data from com port using php. Currently it takes exactly one minute to execute each task. Is there a way to cut short this waiting period?

```
$bytesSent    = dio_write($bbSerialPort, $dataToReboot);



$runForSeconds = new DateInterval("PT10S"); //10 seconds
$endTime = (new DateTime())->add($runForSeconds);

echoFlush(  "Waiting for {$runForSeconds->format('%S')} seconds to recieve data on serial port" );

while (new DateTime() < $endTime) {

    $data = dio_read($bbSerialPort); //this is a blocking call

    if ($data) {
        echoFlush(  "Data Recieved: ". $data );
        $dataToBeep = pack("H*","020816000033C61B");// beep 3
        $bytesbeepSent    = dio_write($bbSerialPort, $dataToBeep);
        $databeep = dio_read($bbSerialPort);
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you show the dio_read() function ?

Comment: @zeflex i think i have already posted the dio_read above there isnt it? the $databeep = dio_read($bbSerialPort); is the dio_read statement isnt it? sorry i am confused..

Comment: Mmm sorry I didn't know that function. I am reading function details ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.dio-read.php

Comment: Quick question, are you sure it's the `dio_read()` slowing your code?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure because there's another small program i try to run without `dio_read()` and it is working fine. So yes I am sure @zeflex

Comment: Sorry I am not expert on this. Why don't you use Php FileSystem [ http://php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php ] instead of Direct IO [ http://php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php ] ?